# Diophantine equation: $n^2=c(4ab-a-b)-b$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

I asked the following question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3295468/diophantine-equation-n2-c4ab-a-b-b), but I did not get a full answer, so I put it here that may be some help.

Let $n$ be a positive integer. The Diophantine equation 
$$
n^2=c(4ab-a-b)-b,\qquad (a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}^+)
$$
is solvable for $n\equiv\pm1\pmod3$, but I stuck for $n\equiv0\pmod3$.

Is there any method to solve it?

thanks!

P.S. The method I used for the cases $n\equiv\pm1\pmod3$ is as follows:
$$
n^2+b=c(4ab-a-b)
$$
Assume for a moment the left-hand side is prime. Since $4ab-a-b>1$ for all $a,b>0$, therefore $c=1$. Now let $n=3k\pm1$ then 
$$
n^2=9k^2\pm6k+1=3(3k^2\pm2k+1)-2=(4ab-a-b)-b=(4b-1)a-2b
$$
If we let $b=1$, we have $a=3k^2\pm2k+1$.

Comment: The problem looks comparable in difficulty to the Erdos-Straus conjecture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Straus_conjecture which remains open (as with this problem, one can handle various congruence classes by explicit algebraic solutions, but these do not cover all cases).

Comment: $9k^2=c(4ab-a-b)-b\overset{a\to u+v\\b\to u-v}{\implies}\\ (8 c u - 2 c - 1)^2 - (8 c v - 1)^2 - (2 c + 36 k^2 + 1)^2 + (36 k^2 + 1)^2 = 0 \implies\\(8 c u - 2 c - 1)^2 - (8 c v - 1)^2 - (2 c + 36 k^2 + 1)^2 + (36 k^2 - 1)^2 + (12 k)^2 = 0$

Comment: @TerryTao, indeed, this $\ 4\!\cdot\! a\!\cdot\! b - a- b\ $ associates immediately with Erdős-Straus.

Answer (score 1):

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3214034/integer-solutions-to-a-two-sheeted-hyperboloid/3214271#3214271

$$z^2=axy+bx+cy+d$$
Use another equation. 
$$q=\frac{A^2-d}{b}$$

And we use solutions to the Pell equation. $k,t -$ any number.

$$p^2-akts^2=1$$

Decisions then write down so.

$$z=Ap^2-((aq+c)t+bk)ps+aAkts^2$$

$$x=qp^2-2kAps+(k((aq+c)t+bk)-aqkt)s^2$$

$$y=ts(((aq+c)t+bk)s-2Ap)$$